# How to implement 'reverse application function' in C++?

Tags: c++, ocaml

I am writing the C++ part of my project which has OCaml as the main language. I much more experienced with OCaml then C++.

I use name binding (in OCaml, variable in C++) when this name is a conceptual point of the logic (to highlight it) or when this name is expected as an argument by more than one function (Possibly, I use it in other cases too, but it isn't important for current context). The following 4 variables look for me more than redundant. As for me they make information noise and decrease code readability.

```
auto caml_level = Caml::Value::of_int(level);
auto caml_api_state = Core::Api::File::open_new(caml_level);
auto polimorpic_variant_hash_status = 
  _api -> extract_and_save_state(caml_api_state);
auto status = statuses.at(polimorpic_variant_hash_status);
```

That's why I had written code that computes `status` without using any additional variables.

```
auto status =
  statuses.at(
    _api -> extract_and_save_state(
      Core::Api::File::open_new(
        Caml::Value::of_int(
          level
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

As for me, the second sample looks better but still unsatisfiable because it is necessary to read this code from down to up. Can I reverse the order of functions to provide the ability to read it up to down? Is it possible to write it as in the 3rd sample where we imagine that C++ has OCaml `|>` operator?

```
auto status =
  level |> Caml::Value::of_int
        |> Core::Api::File::open_new
        |> _api -> extract_and_save_state
        |> statuses.at
```

How to implement a reverse application function in C++?

(These examples are from my trying to implement a bridge between OCaml and C++ with good readability. The bridge contains a lot of conversions like from C int to OCaml int and vise versa, so, potentially it has a lot of variables. And these variables are results of low-level operations, not conceptual points. So, it is not easy to give them good names).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ doesn't let you define new infix operators, so you will have to use identifiers.

Let's assume you are happy to have `| rap >` (spaces optional) instead of `|>`.

```
struct rap_t {
    template <typename F>
    struct wrapper_t { F f; };

    template <typename F>
    friend wrapper_t<F> operator>(rap_t, F&& f) { return { std::forward<F>(f) }; }

    template <typename T, typename F>
    friend std::invoke_result_t<F, T> operator|(T&& t, wrapper_t<F> w)
    { return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(w.f), std::forward<T>(t)); }
} rap;
```

That allows you to

```
auto reuslt =
  level |rap> &Caml::Value::of_int
        |rap> &Core::Api::File::open_new
        |rap> std::bind_front(&Api::extract_and_save_state, _api)
        |rap> &results.at
```

Comment: It isn't so important to have exactly `|>` operator, I asked about any 'reverse application function'. I didn't try to run your code but think that it is what I was looking for.

Comment: BTW if you swap `F` and `T` around you can have `|rap>` syntax ;)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. wouldn't that require a load of `()`?

Comment: Nope. You just need to wrap the function and not the argument. https://godbolt.org/z/MGbcMq

Comment: `#define I |rap` and we can use `I>` pseudo operator (I - is uppercase i)